# Upgrade to Lineage Os 14

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, lineageos

I have a Samsung GT9500 (Intl) which has CM 12. I see that L14.1 is available for my device. Is it possible to simply just upgrade to L14 without bricking my phone. I don't care about losing my data. What steps should I take?

Comment: Just go to recovery and wipe: data, system, cache and simply flash rom, gapps and su if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The Exynos variant of S4 doesn't have official LOS yet. Assuming you're talking about the unofficial one [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9500-orig-develop/rom-lineageos-14-1-samsung-galaxy-s4-t3586561).

Update to the latest recovery possible, e.g. TWRP [here](https://dl.twrp.me/i9500/), or [this one](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=176167) as suggested in the XDA thread.

Do a nandroid backup of what you have now for falling back when needed.

Factory reset - don't think about dirty flashing between major Android versions.

Flash the ROM of choice.